# Save items from a listbox with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

I have a simple question. I have a listbox and I want to save multiples items on my db, but I don't know how to do this with entity framework. I tried to do it with "for", but its not working because the function .Count() catchs all rows in database, and I want just the rows that the user are saving. Anyone can help me? 
I have to save one IDCONCESSSAO to many IDLOCALIDADES.
Here is my code:

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i <= db.SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO.ToList().Count(); i++)
            {
                db.SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO.Add(sinco_localidade_concessao);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, drop down lists and list boxes are only capable of returning scalar types (int, string, etc.) or in the case of a list box a list of scalar types. Typically, the option value will just be the id of the object the user is selecting. Your question doesn't give me a lot of code to work with, but you'll need a view model:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    // any other properties you need to edit

    public List<int> SelectedItemIds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemChoices { get; set; }
}
```

In your action(s), you would need to populate `ItemChoices`. I recommend creating a private method in your controller, since this code is often shared between multiple actions:

```
private void PopulateItemChoices(FooViewModel model)
{
    model.ItemChoices = db.Items.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    { 
        Value = m.Id.ToString(),
        Text = m.Name
    };
}
```

Then, you'd just call this method before returning your view in your create/edit actions:

```
PopulateItemChoices(model);
return View(model);
```

Your view would use this view model as it's model:

```
@model Namespace.To.FooViewModel
```

And then the code for your listbox would be:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedItemIds, Model.ItemChoices)
```

For your post actions:

```
foo.Items = db.Items.Where(m => model.SelectedItemIds.Contains(m.Id));
```

Comment: Thank yoy for your answer, but I already have a listbox working correctly, my problem i'ts just when I try to save more than one data.  In my example at the question, I can save just one row of my collection, and the others are not saving....

Comment: I'm trying to do this way, but the public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemChoices { get; set; } is not working, because SelectListItem isn't recognized. I added namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html at my class, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Jessica. `SelectListItem` is in `System.Web.Mvc` (not `System.Web.Mvc.Html`) and if you not doing it as Chris has suggested then you not doing it correctly. When you post back, `SelectedItemIds` will contain a list of `ID` of the selected items.

Comment: I didn't understand this part: `foo.Items = db.Items.Where(m => model.SelectedItemIds.Contains(m.Id));`. In my code I wrote:  `sinco_localidade_concessao.IDLOCALIDADE = db.SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO.Where(m => sinco_localidade_concessao.SelectedItemIds.Contains(m.IDLOCALIDADE));`  Message error: Erro 3 Cannot implicitly convert type'System.Linq.IQueryable<SINCO_MVC.Models.SINCO_LOCALIDADE_CONCESSAO>' em 'int'

Comment: The LINQ portion is fine. The problem comes in that you're trying to set the result of the query as the value for an int property. This should be stored in whatever collection property you have representing the relationship.